# Using ObjectOutputStream to send a byte array of a public key, encrypt something, and send the encrypted version back

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

So I have a server side public key and private key, my aim is to send the client the public key, the client will encrypt a string with the key, then send the bytes through a stream, and the server will decrypt the byte array.

Exception:

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error

Code:

Sending the encoded key.

```
                    handler.getOos().writeObject(publicKey.getEncoded());
                    handler.getOos().flush();
```

Receiving the byte array (of the encoded key):

```
                        Object o = ois.readObject();
                        if (o instanceof byte[]) {
                            JChat.get().setServerPublicKey(KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec((byte[]) o)));
                            JChat.get().go();
                        }
```

The go() method (here I use a DataOutputStream to send the byte array):

```
public void go() {
    String text = "hello darkness my old friend";
    byte[] encrypted = encrypt(text, serverPublicKey);
    try {
        handler.getDos().write(encrypted);
        handler.getDos().flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Reading the byte array, on the server side:

```
                        int count = dis.available();
                        byte[] in = new byte[count];
                        dis.readFully(in);
                        System.out.println(Server.decrypt(in, Server.get().getPrivateKey()));
```

The decryption method throws this exception:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
at com.archiepking.Server.decrypt(Server.java:97)
at com.archiepking.net.ClientHandler$1.run(ClientHandler.java:44)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? Please note:

> Dos = DataOutputStream Dis = DataInputStream Oos = ObjectOutputStream
>   Ois = ObjectInputStream

I am using two different sockets, one for sending objects and one for datatypes (as my chat application will need both).

What can I do to fix this error?

FURTHER INFORMATION:
Generation of keys:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();
        FileOutputStream fosPublic = new FileOutputStream("public");
        fosPublic.write(publicKeyBytes);
        fosPublic.close();

        byte[] privateKeyBytes = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();
        FileOutputStream fosPrivate = new FileOutputStream("private");
        fosPrivate.write(privateKeyBytes);
        fosPrivate.close();

        publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an ObjectOutputStream why bother converting the public key to a byte array using getEncoded? You can serialize the object directly. e.g.
 handler.getOos().writeObject(publicKey);
Or if you have to use the encoded version, then remove the ObjectOutputStream and use ByteArrayOutputStream instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `DataInputStream.available()` to determine how many bytes to read. That method *does not do what you apparently think that it does*.

From the Javadoc of this method:

> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or
>   skipped over) from this input stream **without blocking by the next
>   caller of a method for this input stream**. The next caller might be the
>   same thread or another thread.  A single read or skip of this many
>   bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.

It just returns the number of bytes that can be read **without blocking**, which can be far less than the actual number of bytes that you sent, especially if you are using network Sockets to send/receive that data.

The solution:

- before writing the bytes, write an `int` with the `writeInt` method that contains the number of bytes that you're writing
- before reading the bytes, call `readInt` to read the number of bytes that will follow, and construct a byte array of the right length from that number.

Comment: This worked! However - how can avoid having to do this?

Comment: @Archie: How can you avoid doing *what*?

Comment: Having to send through the byte array size whenever I want to send a byte array through to a server socket?

Comment: How else would the other side know how many bytes you send? If you are only sending one message per connection, then you could shutdown/close the socket as an indication that the data is complete. But new connections are time consuming so you normally want to send multiple messages on the same connection.